# html table - File export , failed applying demo into mine

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, datatable, export

I'm creating a cool website extract all log from server[(pic) my website screenshot](https://ibb.co/K6fPccY)

**I follow [datatables's demo](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export), but it export from fixed data table, and mine is stocking on applying this to my case**

---

from what I understanding that I just need to insert below js, and src should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

---

- the full code if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Log Management</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  
   
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Log Management</h1>

 

  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.10.01:8000/api/log_all",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response);
            return response.logs                           
          }
        },
        columns: [
  
          { data: "id", title: "id" },
          { data: "message", title: "message" },
          { data: "type", title: "type" },
          { data: "user", title: "created_by" }, 
          { data: "created_at", title: "created_at" }
        ]
      });


      table.draw()
      


      // tried export table
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [
              'csv', 'excel'
          ]
      } );
  } );

      

      var rowData; 

      $(function UndefindLengh(a) {
        if (a !==undefined){
          console.log(a.length);
        }
      })

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });


      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data") {
          inputFields.val("");
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });

      
      

    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="log.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    function AddRow() {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")
      save();



      console.log("Saved Data_added_API_Data:", send_Edit_API_Data);

      // clear value from input box
      $("#input_edit_device_id").val("");
      $("#input_edit_name").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_group").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_ip").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_port").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_ipc_enable").val("");
    }



    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];
    
    function Export() {

      // still thinking
    }

      
  </script>

 <!-- the export isn't work yet -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="Export()">Export</button>

</body>
</html>
```